# Can a gas expand and change its volume at STP by doing work on its surrounding?

Tags: thermodynamics

I came across this question:
1 g of H2 gas expands at STP to occupy double of its original volume. The work done during the process is?

So can a gas expand and change its volume at STP by doing work on its surrounding ie without changing pressure and temperature conditions?

Comment: for given temperature and pressure, only one volume is possible

Comment: Is the question wrong then? thank you for your reply

Comment: The above wording is very poor - better would be "1g of H2 gas at STP expands to occupy double its original volume ...". Even better would be to put "initially" before STP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the volume of $\ce{H2}$ doubles, its final pressure is divided by $2$. And the gas is not at STP any more. But this is probably what the author of the problem wants.

Now this process can be done in a  reversible or in a irreversible way. If this is reversible, the pressure outside and inside are maintained constantly at the same value, and the temperature is maintained at $273$ K. In this case the work is the integral of $pdV = nRT ~\mathrm{log}2 = 0.5  \mathrm{mol} · 8.314~ \mathrm{J·K^{-1} mol^{-1}}·273~ \mathrm{K} ·0.301 =  341.6 ~ \mathrm{J}$. If the work is done irreversibly, there are a lot of ways of carrying it out.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal gas law (I'm assuming you're treating the gas as ideal) says $pV=nRT \implies V = \frac{nRT}{p}$. Since $R$ is a constant, the only way $V$ can change is if you change at least one of $n$, $T$, or $p$.

My guess is that the intent of the questioner is that $n$ doesn't change. So, to double $V$, you need $\frac{T}{p}$ to double, which could be achieved either with a doubling of $T$, a halving of $p$, or changes in both that net out to a doubling of $\frac{T}{p}$ (e.g., $p$ doubles and $T$ increases by four-fold). Regardless, when you do this, the gas isn't at STP any more.

To determine the work, you need to know what $p_{external}$ is during the process.  It could be a fixed pressure.  Or it could be done reversibly, in which case $p_{external}$ would vary continulously and be equal to $p_{gas}$.